# How to write tests for Custom Laravel packages which use migrations files?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I created custom Laravel package that have own migrations. There is no documentation how to test custom packages in laravel documentation.

Do you have any suggestion how to do this, or do you have some package example which have implemented tests good ?

I need to create tables from migration file and fill database after that ...

Comment: What tests are you looking to write?

Comment: I have Cart  package and I save carts and cart_items to db(migration files in package), now I need to create carts and cart_items tables, fill them and then perform test on package functions which uses this tables...

Comment: Cart::add($product);
//test if product is in cart_item table and check if saved data is as expected.

Comment: I found how "taylorotwell" is doing this: https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/6.0/tests/CashierTest.php

but he is creating tables without migration files, I want use migration files....